# Python Flask API not returning data but will print expected data

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to write an API that will query a database of Units.
The unit_id value is taken from the URL and passed into the code below

```
@flask_app.route('/device-data/<unit_id>', methods=['GET'])

def get_data(unit_id):
    try:
        find_device = sql_db.session.query(Unit).filter_by(id = unit_id).all()
        all_devices = Unit.query.all()
        print(unit_id)
        print(find_device)
        print(all_devices)
        print(Unit.query.all()[0])
        return jsonify(find_device)
    except Exception as e:
        error_text = 'Not working: ' + str(e)
        return error_text
```

Nothing is returned except '[]' but when I quit the program using CTRL + C the program will print all the devices to the terminal which shows I am connected to the database.

Is there an error in my query that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

In 5 line you need:

```py
find_device = sql_db.session.query(Unit).filter_by(Unit.id == unit_id).all()
```

But something like this would be better:

```py
find_device = Unit.query.get_or_404(unit_id)
```

This is much more useful, you either get an object or automatically return a 404 error if there is no record in the table with this ID

If in the future you want to search not by ID, then this method will not work, then it will suit you:

```py
find_device = Unit.query.filter_by(Unit.something==something).first_or_404()
```

See more [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#queries-in-views)

Comment: That returns a 404 error, does that mean I'm not actually connected to the database?

Comment: In theory, this means that there is no such record in the table from the database. But I don't know all the details

Comment: This is the confusing part as there are records in the table as they get printed with the print statements, just doesn't seem to let me return them.

Comment: The fact that there are records does not mean that there is a specific record with a specific ID

Comment: Also as i can see, you need to add `int` converter in the url, otherwise you always receive a string

Comment: What's the syntax for adding int converter?

Comment: Use this:`@flask_app.route('/device-data/<int:unit_id>')`. Also visit [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules)

Comment: @JackWeir, what's up?

Comment: It was an issue with how the object was being returned, solved now.

Comment: well, yes, this was the problem for which I showed you the solutions

Comment: Well, yes, but your solutions didn’t fix the problem. I found a solution that did.

Comment: strange that my advice did not help, what kept not working? And also, if you found a solution, then I think it would be better if you leave your answer here or update the question